# How a Jenkins non-privileged user can download a file from workspace?

Tags: jenkins, user-permissions

I have configured Jenkins job as a UI for my Python script, which takes an input file as a parameter, processes it as I need and writes results into output file which is placed besides the script in the job workspace. This job is intended to be executed by regular non-pivelege Jenkins user. And they permissions do not allow them to access anything in the workspace.

How can they retrieve the output file?

Should I configure ext email plugin, so the file will be sent to users as an attachment?

Comment: yes, it seems like an email with attachment is good enough. Just need to make the output file name out of the input file.

Comment: Another approach is to archive the file you need as a build artifact. After archiving the file will be available for download from Jenkins UI.

Comment: @ izzekil  Hey, great idea. Could you post your answer as a solution, so I accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user izzekil mentioned, a good approach is to archive the file you need as a build artifact. After archiving the file will be available for download from Jenkins UI.